# PHP Pagination start page

Tags: php, database, pagination

I have this:

```
<?php
/*paginação
    Place code to connect to your DB here.
*/
include('database.php');    // include your code to connect to DB.

$tbl_name="test_xml";       //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 1;

/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "songs.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 1;                                 //how many items to show per page
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT id FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$prev\">? previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">? previous</span>"; 

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$next\">next ?</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next ?</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        // Your while loop here
        }   ?>
```

I have my pages like this `songs.php?id=4`, but the first page is `1` and I want it to be `4`, the dynamic page I am on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here:

```
for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++) {
    if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?id=$counter\">$counter</a>";
}
```

I would play with the initial `$counter = 1`, perhaps setting it to `$counter = $page`, and see where that takes you